# Ionic build error on ios

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am getting an error while I try to build using the command:

```
$ionic build ios

Error: Cannot find module 'cordova-js/tasks/lib/bundle-browserify'
```

Also I get an error while i try to add platform ios using the command:

```
$ionic platform add ios

Error: Cannot find module 'npmconf'
```

Here are my ionic info :

```
Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.0
ios-deploy version: 1.7.0
ios-sim version: 5.0.1
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v7.2.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62
```

I am new to ionic framework.

What should i do to install the app on the iPhone ?

Comment: I think you need to update your cordova version `npm install -g cordova@latest`. I have cordova 6.5.0 and my ionic version is 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cordova cli` version is old.
Update it to `6.5.0`

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
```